# creating Web service from Outlook 2010 to Domino8.5.2 database

Tags: web-services, outlook, lotus-domino

I am new to web services. From Outlook, i want to create Domino document without Lotus Client installation. How to implement web service? Please any one know answer to this problem means help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can also look into using Domino 8.5.3, the Extension Library and its Domino Data Service which can offer a REST API to the databases on the server.

For more details and information on how to install, administer and implement, please see:
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpViewCategories.xsp?lookupName=Domino%20Data%20Service